# In SQL Server 2005, is it possible to set transaction isolation level on a per-user basis?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

In SQL Server 2005, is it possible to automatically set transaction isolation level to, say, read uncommitted an a per-user basis?

(So for instance, if I set such a login option for user Fred, Fred wouldn't have to remember sprinkle his select statements with NOLOCK hints or remember to add in a set transaction isolation level statement to his sql.)

Comment: How will the users be connecting? If I understand your question correctly then I don't think that there is any way to do it. If all of the users were connecting through a single set of code, then maybe, but if you want it to happen for ad-hoc queries in SSMS, etc. then no.

Comment: I was thinking of setting this regardless of how a user connected (so the setting would have to be in SQL Server itself).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if it is for stored procs you could have code like this in the procs

```
if user_name() in('dbo','username','otherusers','bla') 
set transaction isolation level read uncommitted
else
set transaction isolation level read committed
```

But of course now you have a maintenance problem, all current procs have to be modified

you can also check with suser_sname()  but this really becomes a big PITA

you might also be able to use a [LOGON Trigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326598.aspx) I have not tried and am not sure it will work

Comment: I'll investigate the trigger option. Not exactly what I'd hoped, but it might do the trick -- thanks!

Comment: Ewen - any luck with the trigger option?  I am trying to do exactly the same thing you are, sounds like.  I have a lot of activity that's read-only, and would like to ensure that they're not locking tables.

Comment: @Tom sorry this is 2+ years late, but no, the trigger option won't work. Sure you can say `SET ISOLATION LEVEL` in the trigger, but just as it works in a stored procedure, it reverts to the default when the trigger goes out of scope - so it is only useful for queries that are run inside the logon trigger itself. There is [a more recent discussion about this here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/47357/can-i-force-a-user-to-use-with-nolock).