# Using Logon Trigger for setting isolation level to certain users

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

A little bit of background to the setup before I go into the details. We are using `SQL server 2008R2`, the main database is being updated hourly and the update process can take 15 minutes or longer. Read access to the server has been granted to several groups outside of the team.

We have SQL reporting service set up with over hundreds of reports. These report can be access by 200ish people.

Recently, we are having locking issues. It is more frequent during year end and month ends. The issues is when people try to run a expensive reports, it locks half the table that needs to be updated. We have other job in the server that run daily to rebuild the index. When the 2 issue compound together no one can run any queries.

I was wondering if is possible to create a LOGON trigger to majority of USERS. The trigger will automatically change the user isolation level to `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED`

Have anyone ever done this before? Is there any implication that I don't know?

Thank you for all the help!

Comment: Is your database too big to replicate to another place for running the larger reports?

Comment: In short, yes.  We are looking to get an upgrade. The report are not inheritly large. They usually offer a day range you could choose from. Most time they are run for a few day. However, there are times when users run for years at a time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In SQL Server 2005, is it possible to set transaction isolation level on a per-user basis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685584/in-sql-server-2005-is-it-possible-to-set-transaction-isolation-level-on-a-per-u)